# Location of received messages / intercepting with incoming messages

Tags: windows-phone-7

May i know if there is anyway i can intercept or retrieve the windows phone message from?

I'm trying to create an application, sending the message isn't a problem but i'm having some problem looking for the retrieved message in any means. My plan is to use SMS to transmit data so i'm planning to create a template to display it.

Hope someone can advice. Thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there are no API's to access SMS in WP7 or 7.5 but in future if MS shows mercy then it may be possible.

[You can check this link and vote for SMS access API's.](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1901813-sms-access-api)

Comment: Thank you, know of any *Ahem* unlawful way to get it? sry about that

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the windows phone's messaging app, then you cannot access the data. The API does not provide anyway to access such information, from your application, for security reasons. So, intercepting calls or messages are not allowed.

Comment: Thank you, know of any *Ahem* unlawful way to get it? sry about that